# Where did my reputation go?

Tags: support

I just recently earned a reputation of `2` by editing a user question. I had 159 reputation before. After the edit, I had 161 reputation. Now I see I have 160 reputation. The edit that I made was re edited by someone else. Is that the reason my points vanished?

Comment: Did you downvote an answer? Or are you looking at your rep on meta rather than the main site? meta only syncs every so often.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well, just a moment ago, i down voted an an irrelevant and irrational answer in which a guy was using vulgar and harsh words against coding. Now his answer is completely removed.and I again got my reputation back. So is this the whole story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downvote an answer it will cost you 1 rep. If that answer is subsequently deleted you'll get that rep back again.

Answer (score 2):

You still have 161 reputation on SO. Meta shows 160, but then, it doesn't sync too often.

So relax, your reputation didn't go anywhere. It is where it is supposed to be, in your SO account.

Comment: Well I believe i just got my point back. I lost point due to a down vote to an answer and then the answer was deleted, giving me my point back.

Comment: Good to know. This effectively means you must continue downvoting answers that are irrelevant or low-quality.

Comment: That is our responsibility